# Create navigable tree from csv of path names

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, vba, csv

we are struggling with a large migration project currently and are on the last leg of putting together the user interface.

I have a list of effectively folder paths from the old system like so:

```
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage1/Resources
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage1/Plans
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage1/Finance
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage1/Reporting
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage1/Documents
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage2/Resources
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage2/Plans
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage2/Finance
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage2/Reporting
/Programme1/Project1/WorkPackage2/Documents
/Programme1/Project2/WorkPackage1/Resources
/Programme1/Project2/WorkPackage1/Plans
/Programme1/Project2/WorkPackage1/Finance
/Programme1/Project2/WorkPackage1/Reporting
/Programme1/Project2/WorkPackage1/Documents
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage1/Resources
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage1/Plans
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage1/Finance
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage1/Reporting
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage1/Documents
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage2/Resources
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage2/Plans
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage2/Finance
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage2/Reporting
/Programme2/Project1/WorkPackage2/Documents
/Programme2/Project2/WorkPackage1/Resources
/Programme2/Project2/WorkPackage1/Plans
/Programme2/ Project2/WorkPackage1/Finance
/Programme2/Project2/WorkPackage1/Reporting
/Programme2/Project2/WorkPackage1/Documents
```

Currently these are in a csv, we need to be able to create a navigable object that a user can use to navigate through to find relevant documentation.

[image]

We have a number of issues:

1. There are 114000+ rows in the csv
2. We know the max number of subfolders and it's large (too many to code manually!).
3. There are special characters in the list, including umlauts, french accented chars + greek alphabet chars...
4. A fair number (2000+) rows of the list are longer than 400 characters..
5. We're limited also to what tools we can use. We've been playing with json/jquery/jstree/javascript/excel-vba and have had some success, but its been painful.

If anyone out there has had a similar challenge and any success I'd be interested in finding out how you went about it!

Thanks for looking.

Fohls

Comment: Do you need codes for a js tree?

Comment: What problem did you have with jstree?

Comment: The problem we're facing is when we try to use ajax to lazy load the tree it fails with an invalid character error (due to umlauts and other special chars), if we put the json directly inside the html it will load the jstree ok using our data, but takes an age to load... When we try to use html unordered list (which has been a pain to create) it doesn't seem to lazy load either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd transform the flat paths from the csv into a tree structure and store it in a database. This is essentially the information you have but without the redundancy in the csv. From there it's pretty straight forward transform it to a presentation form. Jstree is one good option. Shouldn't take long to get that up and running.

Comment: Thanks Karim, we've finally got it working now. Turns out jstree's lazy loading actually expects snippets of the tree in the json returned. We thought the ajax call would select the children nodes we wanted by passing the parent in.... once we figured that out we created a effectively a db as you suggest and pulled back dynamic json based on the parent passed into the call...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a mini db (1 table) containing all the folder paths in a single column, plus their parent and whether they had children (figured out using VBA...)

We then used a REST call to pull back the paths/nodes related to the node we clicked on and then pushed those into a function in javascript on the page to then convert to JSON and then use them in JSTREE!

Painful but it works... Now to work out how to make the throbber display when we click....